# Do I still need to code sign our newly created aab before uploading to Google Play, if Play Store will be handling signing?

Tags: android, google-play, code-signing, google-play-console

so far we've been uploading an aab bundle to Google Play and (even-though we're now using app signing by Google Play), we were also code-signing the aab bundle before uploading it like so:

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (System.getenv()["CI"]) { // CI=true is exported by our CI
                storeFile file(System.getenv()["CI_KEYSTORE_PATH"])
                storePassword System.getenv()["CI_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"]
                keyAlias System.getenv()["CI_KEY_ALIAS"]
                keyPassword System.getenv()["CI_KEY_PASSWORD"]
            }
        }
```

We recently decided to migrate to another CI (github actions), so we are wondering **if we still need to code-sign the release aab file** (and thus deal with all the overhead that comes along with uploading secrets to that new CI etc) **since** we've enabled Google Play signing and **Google handles signing for us anyway**.

Could we get away with either using the `debug signingConfig` or better yet not code-sign it at all and have google play handle that upon release?

*p.s We'll be building and deploying our react-native project using fastlane.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, the app signing key is very important as it cannot easily be changed, and if it's compromised, a lot of your users would be at risk.

Now that Google is signing the APK, if you still have a hold of the app signing key as well, you should make sure to keep it in a secure place with restricted ACLs and you should no longer have to sign anything with it.

With *App Signing by Google Play* comes the possibility of signing the App Bundle with a different key (called the **upload key**). Although not mandatory, it is recommended to take advantage of this feature since it allows you to keep your app signing key secure and only use the upload key to sign the App Bundle uploaded to the Play Console. More on this key here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

If the upload key gets compromised or is lost, you can simply request Google to create a new one and this won't impact your users.

Note that all App Bundles need to be signed on upload to the Play Console (and it can't be a debug certificate), so unless the Bundles you build are only used for testing and you don't have intention of uploading them to Play, you should always sign them (preferably with the upload key).

Hope that helps,

Comment: Got it, so to sum things up, my options are:

A) keep signing with the actual signing files, all-though there's no benefit from doing that since google will re-sign anyway

B) Sign using an upload key